# Why is it possible to reassign a List<T> property in Realm?

Tags: list, realm, swift3

In **Realm**, it is required to name a `List<T>` property as let, like:

```
class Dog:Object {
    dynamic name = "doggy"
    let mate = List<Dog>()
}

let dog1 = Dog()
dog1.name = "Bark"
let dog2 = Dog()
dog2.name = "Brave"
dog1.mates.append(dog2)
```

As `mates` is a `let` variable. You can't reassign it by

```
let dog3 = Dog()
dog3.name = "Bright"
dog3.mates.append(dog2)
//dog1.mates = dog3.mates // Cannot assign to property: 'mates' is a 'let' constant
```

But you can reassign it by

```
dog1["mates"] = dog3.mates // works
dog1.setValue(dog3.mates, forKey: "mates") //works
```

My question is why "reassign a `let` variable" allows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All model properties in Realm are mutable under the hood. However, generic properties don't generate objective-c getters and setters, and therefore can't be overridden, which is why `List` and `RealmOptional` properties in Realm must be defined as `let`, because if they were `var` and re-assigned via the native setter, Realm wouldn't know about and Bad Things would happen.

Since Realm *can* handle `setValue(_:forKey:)`, that works.